# Adding noise to image using localvar

Tags: image, matlab, noise

I am not able to find example code of imnoise function of matlab using 'localvar' anywhere. Can anyone help me, as i am having really hard time to locate it??
As per matlab documentation, 
J = imnoise(I,'localvar',V) 
adds zero-mean, Gaussian white noise of local variance, V, to the image I.  V is an array of the same size as I.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean something like this:

```
clc;
close all; clear all;


A = imread('peppers.png');

B = imnoise(A,'localvar',0.05*rand(size(A)));

imshow(B)
```

which gives this:

[image]

**EDIT**: Using the additional input parameters `image_intensity` and `var`, here is what you can get:

```
C = imnoise(A,'localvar',rand(1,100),rand(1,100));
```

The result is the following:

[image]

Moreover, you can specify a liner relationship between the variance and the image intensity, for example, by defining the variables like so:

```
image_intensity = rand(1,100);
var = ones(1,100); % variance is linearly proportional to image intensity.
```

which outputs this:

[image]

Of course you can play around as much as you like with the parameters; just be careful in defining the vectors `image_intensity` and `var` since their lengths must match.

Comment: Your answer seems to be correct. What about adding noise with second variable,  J = imnoise(I,'localvar',IMAGE_INTENSITY,VAR)?

Comment: Please see my updated answer. If it helps you please accept it as well :)

Comment: Thanks for answering. Can u provide a link to additional study material on this.

Comment: Great you're welcome. You might be interested in this wikipedia page : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_noise. Otherwise I don't have much to suggest sorry :)

Comment: Anyone else can help?

Comment: Is there an equivalent of this in Octave? (The `imnoise` function in octave doesn't support `localvar`.)